# Entity Framework 5 - LINQ syntax error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, filter

I have the following code where I am creating a IList that I need to filter by the data in another list called List. The locations list represents the locations a user is allowed to view based on their permissions. I am new to LINQ and am confused with error I get (C# Unknown method "Where(?)" of "System.Ling.IQueryable". I have tried various syntax arrangement using either Contains() and Any() or both to no avail. I feel like it's something very basic that I don't    understand about doing this. Here is the code:

```
 ----- users locations
 using System;
 using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
 using System.Linq;


 namespace Decking.Models
 {
    public class locations
    {
        [Key]
        public string org_id { get; set; }
    }
 }

 ///////// here is the view model

 using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
 using System;

 namespace Decking.Models
 {

    public class InventoryViewModel
    {        

        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }
        public DateTime metric_dt { get; set; }
        public int? item_id { get; set; }
        public int? loc_type_id { get; set; }
        public string trlr_nbr { get; set; }
        public string user_id { get; set; }
        public string org_id { get; set; }
        public Double numerator { get; set; }       

        //these are the child entities
        [UIHint("ClientItem")]
        public ItemViewModel Items
        {
           get;
           set;
        }

        [UIHint("ClientLocTypes")]
        public LocTypesViewModel LocTypes
        {
           get;
           set;
        }

        [UIHint("ClientOrgsByUser")]
        public OrgsByUserViewModel OrgsByUser
        {
           get;
           set;            
        }

    }
 }
 ///////// code to populate the view model

 public IList<InventoryViewModel> GetAll(List<locations> locs)
 {     
  IList<InventoryViewModel> result = new List<InventoryViewModel>();

     result = entities.inventory.Select(inventory => new
 InventoryViewModel
    {

        id = inventory.id,
        metric_dt = inventory.metric_dt,
        item_id = inventory.item_id,
        loc_type_id = inventory.loc_type_id,
        trlr_nbr = inventory.trlr_nbr,
        org_id = inventory.org_id,
        numerator = inventory.numerator,
        user_id = inventory.user_id,

        Items = new ItemViewModel()
        {
            item_id = inventory.items.item_id,
            item_desc = inventory.items.item_desc,
        },

        LocTypes = new LocTypesViewModel()
        {
            loc_type_id = inventory.loc_types.loc_type_id,
            loc_desc = inventory.loc_types.loc_desc,
        },

        OrgsByUser = new OrgsByUserViewModel()
        {
            user_id = inventory.user_id,
            //mgr_emp_nbr = inventory.mgr,
            org_id = inventory.org_id,

        },
 }).Where(e => e.metric_dt == DateTime.Today  && e.org_id

        ==locs.Any(o=>o.org_id)) // this doesn't work

 //}).Where(e => e.metric_dt == DateTime.Today  && e.org_id == "SGF") //  

        this works
 .ToList();

   return result;
}

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated! Thank so much!
```

Comment: try locs.Any(o=>o.org_id != null))

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in `e.org_id == locs.Any(o=>o.org_id)`. As I can see in your working example, your org_id is a `string`.

I guess what you are trying to do is `.Where(e => e.metric_dt == DateTime.Today  && locs.Any(o=>o.org_id == e.org_id))`